# Adding custom columns inside document library that is defined in custom site definition via visual studio for sharepoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint

I'm trying to define custom columns for document library inside site definition for dynamic site creation in my Sharepoint project.

I've created site definition inside visual studio and the onet.xml is defined in the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Title="AuditSiteDefinition1" Revision="2" ListDir="" xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <NavBars>
  </NavBars>
  <Configurations>
    <Configuration ID="0" Name="AuditSiteDefinition1">
      <Lists>
        <List Title="Documents" Url="Documents" FeatureId="00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" Type="101" VersioningEnabled="True" EnableMinorVersions="True" />
      </Lists>
      <SiteFeatures>
      </SiteFeatures>
      <WebFeatures>
      </WebFeatures>
      <Modules>
        <Module Name="DefaultBlank" />
      </Modules>
    </Configuration>
  </Configurations>
  <Modules>
    <Module Name="DefaultBlank" Url="" Path="">
      <File Url="default.aspx">
      </File>
    </Module>
  </Modules>
</Project>
```

As you can see I define the document library in the Lists tag but i can not find a way how to define additional columns inside the document library.

I came in mind to define this columns as Hashtable props when I'm going to add a document via code and to leave the structure as mentioned previous.

My question is:
What is the preferable way to define custom columns in my document library that is defined via visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

It is Ok to define the additional data for every added document as metadata (via Hashtable) when you add the document in a dynamic manner.

```
public string AddNewDocument(DocumentSPViewModel document, Guid siteId, string docLib, byte[] content, string rootsiteurl, out Guid uniqueId)
        {
            Hashtable props = new Hashtable();

            props.Add("Title", document.Title);
            props.Add("vti_title", document.Title);
            props.Add("FullName", document.ModifiedBy);

            if (document.DocumentType != null)
            {
                props.Add("DocumentTypeId", document.DocumentType.Id.ToString());
                props.Add("DocumentTypeTitle", document.DocumentType.Title);
            }
            props.Add("Active", document.Active);

            return AddNewDocument(siteId, docLib, content, document.Name, props, rootsiteurl, out uniqueId);
        }

        public string AddNewDocument(Guid siteId, string docLibName, byte[] content, string fileName, Hashtable documentProperties, string rootsiteurl, out Guid uniqueId)
        {
            SPWeb web = null;
            SPSite site = null;

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("FileName");
                if (content == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Content");
                if (content.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("Content");

                site = new SPSite(rootsiteurl);

                web = site.OpenWeb(siteId);
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(docLibName);

                string generatedFileName = "Test"

                SPFile file = folder.Files.Add(generatedFileName, content, documentProperties, true);
                uniqueId = file.UniqueId;

                return generatedFileName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                web.Close();
                web.Dispose();
                site.Close();
                site.Dispose();
            }
        }
```